# How can I programatically add a paragraph type field to custom block?

Tags: blocks, paragraphs

Currently, I already built a custom block programmatically, now I want to add a paragraph-type field programmatically to this block but don't know how to do it.
The reason is that I want to add/remove the paragraph-type field dynamically in the form block(just like the repeater field type in WordPress).
Something like

```
$form['article_paragraphs'] = [
'#type' => 'paragraph',
'#title' => $this->t('Create article feature'),
'#description' => $this->t('This field will allow you to add/remove feature(contain the title, description)'),
'#default_value' => $this->configuration['article_paragraphs'],
.....
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paragraphs are entities and can only be added to other entities, in this case a custom block type.

Comment: @auk4 Could you elaborate in more detail and provide me an example? Thank you

Comment: Start with /admin/structure/block-content and add a block type with a paragraph field. Don't try to deploy this in code, export the config and put the yaml files in the module config install folder (remove the uuid line).

Comment: @auk4 I already add block type with a paragraph field inside, but then how I can programmatically add more fields (textfield, email, fieldset...) to this block type?